# Connection between modular equation and elliptic integral

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals, modular-function

Why does the modular equation
\begin{align}
\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)} = n\frac{K'(l)}{K(l)} \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{align}
where $n$ is an integer, imply a relation $y=f(x)$ such that
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}} = \frac{M(k,l)dy}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-l^2y^2)}} \tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{align}
for some $M(k,l)$? (See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularEquation.html).

To give an idea of what I already know, I know about elliptic functions and integrals, so I know $K$ and $K'$ are complete elliptic integrals. I also know a tiny bit about modular functions and the modular group.

Comment: Did you mean $k,l$ are such that $\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)} = n\frac{K'(l)}{K(l)}$ for some integer $n$ ?

Comment: Yes. I have changed it.

Comment: And in $(2)$ I think you mean $y=f(x)$

Comment: This is based on the complicated  theory of transformation of elliptic integrals brought into prominence by Jacobi in his *Fundamental Nova*. The key aspect is that if $n$ is a positive integer then there exists a rational function $y=f(x) $ which allows you to get $(2)$. You can have a look at my blog posts for more details: https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/10/elementary-approach-to-modular-equations-jacobi-transformation-theory-1.html?m=0

Comment: Further one can establish $(1)$ using $(2)$ and that is the logical flow. I don't think Jacobi anywhere tries to show that $(1)$ implies $(2)$.